# Group By & Eliminate varying Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

Scenario 1:

Table:

```
id column1 column2
1  "bla"   "foo"
2  "bla"   "bar"
```

I want to group by `column1` and get null for `column2`, cause there's not the same value in all rows.

Scenario 2:

Table:

```
id column1 column2
1  "bla"   "foo"
2  "bla"   "foo"
```

I want to group by `column1` and get `foo` for `column2`, cause all values of `column2` are equal.

Is it possible to solve this by a sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to group by `column1`, one way to know if `column2` has all same values is to check if `max(column2) = min(column2)`, therefore this should work:

```
select column1, case 
                    when max(column2) = min(column2) then max(column2)
                    else null
                end as col2
  from tabletest
 group by column1;
```

**Edit**

If your `column2` cannot accept `null` values, then the above query is ok, otherwise you need the following one to handle cases when `column2` is `null`:

```
select t.column1, case 
                      when (select max(1) from tabletest where column2 is null and column1 = t.column1) = 1 then null
                      when max(t.column2) = min(t.column2) then max(t.column2)
                      else null
                  end as col2
  from tabletest t
 group by t.column1;
```

The only difference is that we need to add a `case` condition to cover the case of when `column2 is null`

Comment: This should be _much_ faster than subselect or join. Nice.

Comment: If column2 can contain NULLs, that won't work if you have two rows, one with a NULL and one with a value.

Comment: @eaolson Thanks for pointing that out. I have proposed a new query for that

Comment: dbms is sql server 2008. well done for my posted example...but i forgot that data type of column2 in my case is an unique identifier, on which max() and min() wont' work. is there any way to do the same with guids?

Comment: @anonymous Now I am confused. If `column2` is `uniqueidentifier` as you said, then, by definition, `column2` cannot have repeated values

Comment: of course it could, cause column2 is an foreign key. another solution i found is to convert uniqueidentifer in binary and then perform min and max

Comment: @anonymous You are right, my mistake. Although newId() returns a unique ID, sure you can store the same guid value. If converting them to binary works for you, then I guess you have your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id = t.id ,
       col1 = t.col1 ,
       col2 = case when t1.N < 2 then t.col2 end
from myTable t
join ( select col1,N=count(distinct col2)
       from myTable
       group by col1
     ) t1 on t1.col1 = t.col1
```